# How to check for spaces before or after a string in excel

Tags: excel

I have a column containing values spread over several rows. Some of the values have a space either in front or at the end of the value. Is there a simple way to find out such occurences in a excel sheet.

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you have the data in column A, you could enter the following formula in any column starting from row 1 and drag down to identify spaces

`=IF(OR(LEFT(A1,1)=" ",RIGHT(A1,1)=" "),TRUE,FALSE)`

TRUE will identify data with a leading or trailing space

Comment: It can be simplified as: OR(LEFT(A1,1)=" ",RIGHT(A1,1)=" ")

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is.  So the original length is

```
=len(A1)
```

right?  If you trim it and it returns a different length, then there was a space at either the beginning or end of the value, which would be-

```
=if(len(A1)-len(trim(A1))>0,"yes","no")
```

Comment: This will not work in all cases as Trim also removes double spaces. Plus isn't this an exact copy of a previous answer?

Answer (score 4):

Do you want the check in a separate column? If so, try adding this in a column next to the data (or anywhere you want, as long as you reference the column):

```
=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(TRIM(A1))>0,"SPACE!","")
```

This would go in cell `B1`. Note that this will also catch instances with multiple spaces before/after the string. However as @YograjGupta mentions, this will also return true if there are consecutive spaces inside the string.

[image]

Comment: It will give "SPACE!", if cell value contains more then one space in between, like "ADSF<space><space><space>ASDF".

Answer (score 2):

If none of the other answers in this post work, but Sachin Pandit's "CODE(160)" formula does, then you didn't actually have "spaces" as such [CHAR(32)] but rather some non-breaking whitespaces [CHAR(160)].
To deal with text that has double (or more) CHAR(32) spaces between words, you could use this formula:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"  ",""),1)=" ",RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"  ",""),1)=" "),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than below code, rest did not work - This is to only find leading spaces ,

```
=IF(CODE(LEFT(<reference cell>,1))=160,"Leading Space","No Leading space")
```